# how to expose business tier to a presentation tier?

Tags: php, n-tier-architecture

I think I do understand n-tier concept. I however have problems figuring out how would I communicate with **Business tier** from **presentation tier**?

What do companies use to expose their business layer? I've looked at apache Thrift - is that what's usually done when building multi-tier apps?

P.S> **Business tier** and **presentation tier** are physically separated - on different servers.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways:
1. Web services
2. RMI
3. Message Queues ( although this is more of a business layer to business layer integration)